# SQL Server Express connection string / FluentNHibernate

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, fluent-nhibernate, connection-string

I'm having some issues with my connection string. I've been testing a lot of different strings and approaches and now I'm stuck.

```
private static void InitializeSessionFactory()
{
    _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                          .ConnectionString(
 @"Server=Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;DataBase=carDB.mdf;User ID=sa;Password=xxxSecretxxx;")
                          .ShowSql()
            )
            .Mappings(m =>
                      m.FluentMappings
                          .AddFromAssemblyOf<Car>())
            .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg).Create(true, false))
            .BuildSessionFactory(); 
    }
```

(I know I shouldn't be using 'sa' at all - why I've done so is solely because of lack of management software so I had to use the only account there were)

I am using a SQL Server Express database.

The exception I get is this:

> *An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory.
>
>   Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.*

This is my inner exception

> *A network-related or instance-specific error
>   occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.
>
>   The server was not found or was not accessible.
>
>   Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>
>   (provider: SQL Network Interfaces,
>   error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)*

Does anyone know how I should approach this? I've spent hours trying to get this to work.

Comment: Your SQL Server can be **either** Compact (single file with `.sdf` extension), **or** Express (at least two files - one `.mdf`, another `.ldf`) - but not both at the same time! So which is it??

Comment: Thanks, then it's a Express.. will edit my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the connection string, you don't specify the database *file* but the database *name*. So it shouldn't be

```
@"Server=Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;DataBase=carDB.mdf;User ID=sa;Password=xxxSecretxxx;"
```

but

```
@"Server=Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;DataBase=carDB;User ID=sa;Password=xxxSecretxxx;"
```

provided that the database really has the name `carDB` and not some other like `Cars`.

Also, I recommend using the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` class to build connection strings, as it guarantees for syntactically correct connection strings.

On a side note: You do know that you can install the management tools (like SQL Server Management Studio for SQL Server Express) for the Express edition, too? This makes things much easier.

Comment: "On a side note: You do know that you can install the management tools (like SQL Server Management Studio for SQL Server Express) for the Express edition, too? This makes things much easier." - Yes, I've downloaded the tools and will install / configure my SQL Express as soon as i get home. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly what edition of SQL Server you're using. It's ether Express or Compact.

If it's SQL Express then try this:

```
@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=carDB;User ID=sa;Password=********;"
```

For SQL Compact usually enough to specify the path and the name of db file:

```
@"Data Source=path\\carDB.sdf;"
```

But for SQL Compact you probably need another provider `MsSqlCeConfiguration.Standard`

Comment: Thank you, I will try this when I get home! =)